# What is the star particle that rises from my non-shiny Pokémon in battle?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

My Pokémon is not shiny, but every time I use it in battle, a star particle rises from it. Does anyone know what it is?

I think it's worth mentioning that he had been infected with Pokérus and is now immune.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps get a "Strange Ending" in [Pokéstar Studios](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9star_Studios)?

> If the player manages to create a strange ending with their own Pokémon, that Pokémon will become a star and **will be given a special entry animation, much like when a Shiny Pokémon is sent out**
> <sub>(Emphasis my own)</sub>